# How to add an entry to svn:ignore without deleting previous value using Subversion commandline

Tags: svn, ant

I need to add some files to svn:ignore from the command line.

BUT I need to do this without removing previous values of the svn:ignore property. If I use the command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.jar" .
```

it sets the correct ignore value but erases every previous value, which is not what I want.

Using `svn propedit` isn't suitable for me since I need to execute this from an Ant script.

**EDIT:** portability is not an issue for me (I have to work on windows) but I cannot install third-party Ant libraries, I only have the Subversion command line.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

**FINAL EDIT:** to enyone interested, I implemented the suggested solution in the Ant script this way:

```
<!-- Read current values and write them to a file -->
<exec executable="svn" output="${build}/current-props-file">
    <arg value="propget" />
    <arg value="svn:ignore" />
    <arg value="." />
</exec>
<!-- Reload the file, stripping away the value possibly already present to avoid duplicate -->
<loadfile srcfile="${build}/current-props-file" property="cleaned-props">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains negate="true">
            <contains value=".jar" /> 
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo message="cleaned-props: ${cleaned-props}" />
<!-- Create file with final values to set -->
<echo file="${build}/cleaned-props-file" message="${cleaned-props}*.jar" />
<!-- Set property values -->
<exec executable="svn">
    <arg value="propset" />
    <arg value="svn:ignore" />
    <arg value="--file" />
    <arg value="${build}/cleaned-props-file" />
    <arg value="." />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the value of svn:ignore before updating it, then append a new line to this value and set the new value:

```
$ ignores=$(svn propget svn:ignore .)
$ ignores="$ignores"$'\n'"*.jar"
$ svn propset svn:ignore "$ignores" .
```

You can also use temporary file to store the older value:

```
$ svn propget svn:ignore . > /tmp/ignores
$ echo "*.jar" >> /tmp/ignores
$ svn propset svn:ignore -F /tmp/ignores .
$ rm -f /tmp/ignores
```

But since you're going to execute this code from an Ant script, I'd propose to implement that functionality with [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/). The code should look like this:

```
File target = new File("");
SVNWCClient client = SVNClientManager.newInstance().getWCClient();
SVNPropertyData oldValue = client.doGetProperty(
    target,
    SVNProperty.IGNORE,
    SVNRevision.WORKING,
    SVNRevision.WORKING
);
String newValue = SVNPropertyValue.getPropertyAsString(oldValue.getValue()) +
                  '\n' + "*.jars";
client.doSetProperty(
    target,
    SVNProperty.IGNORE,
    SVNPropertyValue.create(newValue),
    false,
    SVNDepth.EMPTY,
    ISVNPropertyHandler.NULL,
    Collections.emptyList()
);
```

In order to run this code form your ant script, put it into main method of some class IgnoresUpdate. Compile and make .class file available for the script. Then you can invoke it as follows:

```
<java classname="IgnoresUpdate" fork="true">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="/path/to/compiled/IgnoresUpdate"/>
        <pathelement location="/path/to/svnkit.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

However, as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156554/david) pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648967/1065967), you can use [ignore task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#ignore) which seems like the best solution in general (although it may be not applicable for you case).

Comment: Wow, thank you for your large answer. Why use SVNKit in the Ant script? I mean, I don't know how to use your last code snippet (creating an Ant additional task?), but now that you wrote about it, I think I could do that work in the Ant script itself (getting the propget output and putting it into an Ant property, then adding the missing value and calling a propset).

Comment: I've updated the answer, so it now has all the possible options. As to your question, one has to put SVNKit on a classpath in order to use it within an Ant script. So, you might want to avoid that and invoke svn commands instead, although that's not very portable.

Comment: You're right, Vadishev, it's not very portable but it's not an issue in my case: where I work they have fixed os (windows) and svn client preinstalled, BUT it would be a problem to force installing another java library. Anyway, I'm going with your first suggestion: propget then propset. Thanks for your help all!

Comment: Marking this answer as correct because it drove me to the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the svnant tasks?  You can directly integrate SVN client functionality into your Ant builds with it.  It also has an [ignore task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#ignore), which looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Yes but I need to keep Ant requirements to a minimum, so I went for the command line (installing svnant task in my current working place would be a burden).